# Problem retrieving map value

Tags: apex, trigger

Hi guys this is my code:

```
trigger ROIDUpdate on RO_Item__c (before insert, before update) {


//Setting the mapping

    Map<Decimal,RO_Item__c> m = new Map<Decimal,RO_Item__c>();
    Set<Decimal> ROH_Numbers = new Set<Decimal>();
    for (RO_Item__c ROI :Trigger.New){

        //system.debug('<---New Repair Order Item--->');

        if (ROI.SOD_AUTO_KEY__c!=Null){


                    m.put(ROI.SOD_AUTO_KEY__c, ROI);
                    ROH_Numbers.add(ROI.ROH_AUTO_KEY__c);

                    //system.debug('Map key:'+ m.get(ROI.SOD_AUTO_KEY__c) );
        }  
    }

                            system.debug('-----Result ROHs -----: ' + ROH_Numbers);


    //Looking for the Sales Order Item that matches the Repair Order SOD Auto Key
    List<SO_Item__c> soilst = [SELECT SOId__c, SOD_AUTO_KEY__c, Unit_Price__c
                                 FROM SO_Item__c
                                 WHERE SOD_AUTO_KEY__c in :m.keySet()];

    /*LOOKING THE CORRESPONDING ROH FOR EACH ROD*/
    Map<Decimal, Repair_Order__c> ROHMap = new Map<Decimal, Repair_Order__c>();
    List<Repair_Order__c> ROHMapList = [SELECT id, ROH_AUTO_KEY__c FROM Repair_Order__c WHERE ROH_AUTO_KEY__c IN :ROH_Numbers] ;
    for(Repair_Order__c ROH : ROHMapList){
        ROHMap.put(ROH.ROH_AUTO_KEY__c, ROH);
    }
    system.debug('ROHMAP: '+ ROHMap);



    //Write the ID of the Sales Order into the Repair Order. Field SO_ID__c under RO_Item__c
    for(SO_Item__c b :soilst){

        for(RO_Item__c ROitem:Trigger.New){
            //Fill ROI with Sales Orders
            if (b.SOD_AUTO_KEY__c!=Null){

                if (ROitem.SOD_AUTO_KEY__c==b.SOD_AUTO_KEY__c){

                    ROitem.SO_ID__c= b.SOId__c;
                    ROitem.SO_Unit_Price__c=b.Unit_Price__c;
                    //system.debug('SO ID to be inserted:'+ b.SOId__c ); 
                }    
            }   
        }
    }

    for (RO_Item__c CurrentItem : Trigger.New){
        //Fill Repair Order Header SF ID on each ROI
        system.debug('Final Loop - Trigger.New: ' + Trigger.New);
        system.debug('Look for this ROH_AUTO_KEY: '+ CurrentItem.ROH_AUTO_KEY__c);
        system.debug('ROHMAP inside Trigger New: '+ ROHMap);
        system.debug('Current Get Map: ' + ROHMap.get(CurrentItem.ROH_AUTO_KEY__c));

        if (ROHMap.get(CurrentItem.ROH_AUTO_KEY__c) != Null){
            system.debug('Entered the final if');
            CurrentItem.ROId__c = ROHMap.get(CurrentItem.ROH_AUTO_KEY__c).id;
            //system.debug('ROH Value assignment -- ROD: '+ CurrentItem.ROD_AUTO_KEY__c + 'ROD`s ROH: '+CurrentItem.ROH_AUTO_KEY__c + 'RO ID: '+ CurrentItem.ROId__c);
            }
        }

}
```

When I'm trying to retrieve a value in the `ROHMap` it's always null even though the value that I'm passing exists in the map. What am I doing wrong? I can't see it.

Basically the code is not entering the final if.

This is what I'm getting in the debug logs:

[image: debug log result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that floating point numeric values correctly define equals to ignore the scale, but the hashCode function considers scale part of the mix. As such, because Maps use hashCode when selecting a bucket for the key, you have to ensure that you set the scale on your values consistently when inserting and querying the map. If you don't, you get this sort of failure to find the object in the map.

Comment: Hey @Phil, how do you suggest that I should adjust the scale in this situation?

Comment: Looks like saves the decimal value like an integer into the Map. So I'm doing `ROHMap.get(integer.valueof(CurrentItem.ROH_AUTO_KEY__c))` and apparently it works. Will test it further with more data.

Comment: When you put in use thedecimal.setScale(8) as the key and when you get use the exact same approach. 8 is randomly chosen. I don't know what scale you have set on the fields in the DB you are using...